# Strange blocking behavior with python multiprocessing queue put() and get()

Tags: python, linux, queue, multiprocessing, blocking

I have written a class in python 2.7 (under linux) that uses multiple processes to manipulate a database asynchronously. I encountered a very strange blocking behaviour when using `multiprocessing.Queue.put()` and `multiprocessing.Queue.get()` which I can't explain.

Here is a simplified version of what I do:

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue

class MyDB(object):  

    def __init__(self):
        self.inqueue = Queue()

        p1 = Process(target = self._worker_process, kwargs={"inqueue": self.inqueue})
        p1.daemon = True
        started = False
        while not started:
            try:
                p1.start()
                started = True
            except:
                time.sleep(1)  

        #Sometimes I start a same second process but it makes no difference to my problem 
        p2 = Process(target = self._worker_process, kwargs={"inqueue": self.inqueue})
        #blahblah... (same as above)

    @staticmethod
    def _worker_process(inqueue):
        while True:
            #--------------this blocks depite data having arrived------------

            op = inqueue.get(block = True)
            #do something with specified operation

            #---------------problem area end--------------------
            print "if this text gets printed, the problem was solved"

    def delete_parallel(self, key, rawkey = False):
        someid = ...blahblah
        #--------------this section blocked when I was posting the question but for unknown reasons it's fine now
        self.inqueue.put({"optype": "delete", "kwargs": {"key":key, "rawkey":rawkey}, "callid": someid}, block = True) 
        #--------------problem area end----------------
        print "if you see this text, there was no blocking or block was released"
```

If I run the code above inside a test (in which I call `delete_parallel` on the `MyDB` object) then everything works, but if I run it in context of my entire application (importing other stuff, inclusive pygtk) strange things happen:

For some reason `self.inqueue.get` blocks and never releases despite `self.inqueue` having the data in its buffer. When I instead call `self.inqueue.get(block = False, timeout = 1)` then the call finishes by raising Queue.Empty, despite the queue containing data. `qsize()` returns 1 (suggests that data is there) while `empty()` returns True (suggests that there is no data).

Now clearly there must be something somewhere else in my application that renders `self.inqueue` unusable by causing acquisition of some internal semaphore. However I don't know what to look for. Eclipse dubugging becomes useless once a blocking semaphore is reached.

**Edit 8** (cleaning up and summarizing my previous edits) Last time I had a similar problem, it turned out that pygtk was hijacking the global interpreter lock, but I solved it by calling `gobject.threads_init()` before I called anything else. Could this issue be related?

When I introduce a `print "successful reception"` after the `get()` method and execute my application in terminal, the same behaviour happens at first. When I then terminate by pressing CTRL+D I suddenly get the string "successful reception" inbetween messages. This looks to me like some other process/thread is terminated and releases the lock that blocks the process that is stuck at `get()`.

Since the process that was stuck terminates later, I still see the message. What kind of process could externally mess with a Queue like that? `self.inqueue` is only accessed inside my class.

Right now it seems to come down to this queue which won't return anything despite the data being there:

[image: defect queue]

the `get()` method seems to get stuck when it attempts to receive the actual data from some internal pipe. The last line before my debugger hangs is:

```
res = self._recv()
```

which is inside of `multiprocessing.queues.get()`
Tracking this internal python stuff further I find the assignments
`self._recv = self._reader.recv` and `self._reader, self._writer = Pipe(duplex=False)`.

**Edit 9**
I'm currently trying to hunt down the import that causes it. My application is quite complex with hundreds of classes and each class importing a lot of other classes, so it's a pretty painful process. I have found a first candidate class which Uses 3 different `MyDB` instances when I track all its imports (but doesn't access `MyDB.inqueue` at any time as far as I can tell). The strange thing is, it's basically just a wrapper and the wrapped class works just fine when imported on its own. This also means that it uses `MyDB` without freezing. As soon as I import the wrapper (which imports that class), I have the blocking issue.

I started rewriting the wrapper by gradually reusing the old code. I'm testing each time I introduce a couple of new lines until I will hopefully see which line will cause the problem to return.

Comment: If you really build your queue by `Queue()` use `block=True` in `put` calls have no sense: `Queue()` create a queue with `maxsize=0` that means a queue without limits and `block=True` in `put` calls waiting for free room in the queue and so will never block on an unlimited queue.

Comment: You're right, I tend to do that out of habit of being explicit. I have rewritten the entire class I mentioned in my 9th edit and the problem disappeared. For the rewritten class I tried to get rid of as many imports as possible. I still don't know why, but it seems like the problem is related to importing classes. My code is too huge and complex to put it here, but if I find the core of the problem I will extract the relevant lines and post it here.

Answer (score 1):

`queue.Queue` uses internal threads to maintain its state. If you are using GTK then it will break these threads. So you will need to call `gobject.init_threads()`.

It should be noted that `qsize()` only returns an approximate size of the queue. The real size may be anywhere between 0 and the value returned by `qsize()`.

Comment: Thanks, but I tried with and without gobject.threads_init(). It made no difference...